# Html/Php: echo in value attribute only displays the 1st character of a string

Tags: php, html

I retrieved all the fields of a specific row in my database that I stored in the `$tab` array, `$tab[4]` corresponds to the field "address" in my database (and its type is varchar(255)). 
The problem is that when I "echo" `$tab[4]` in the "value" attribute of an input, I only get the beginning of the string.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>

<?php

    try
    {
      $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=monsitexfqadmin.mysql.db;dbname=m...min;charset=utf8','m...min', 'mypass',array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT));
    }
    catch(Exception $e)

    {
      die('Error : '.$e->getMessage());
    }


    $req = $bdd -> prepare("SELECT * FROM users2") or die(errorInfo()); //
    $req->execute();  

    $tab=$req->fetch();

    $rue=$tab[4];

    echo "$ rue = ".$rue."<br>";
    echo "type of $rue = ".gettype($rue)."<br>";
    echo "size of $rue = ".strlen($rue)."<br>";

    ?>
      <input type="text" value=<?php echo $rue;?>>

</body>
</html>
```

result:

[image: here]

I really don't see why I have this result, any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Put quotes around the value: `<input type="text" value="<?php echo $rue; ?>">`

Comment: FYI, you should be careful about echoing out PDO connection error messages.  They can often contain credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the quotes ( `"` ) around the `value` attribute.

Actually, your code's output is:

```
<input type="text" value=St John Street>
```

... Which, for the HTML parser, means that `St` is the value of the `value` attribute, and `John` and `Street` are boolean attributes --- which is emphasized by the code syntax highlighting.

BTW, and as said by @cale_b and @Brad: you should escape your address with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) --- note: this remark is only valid if the output content comes from the user and has not been already escaped of course.

Comment: What *should* it look like?

Comment: this is a comment and considered as being of very low-quality for an answer. Edit: This comment as per their original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44464794/1

Comment: Better, but show what it SHOULD look like.  And, don't forget to include a reference to using htmlspecialchars, otherwise they might end up with something like `<input type="text" value="Some "Cool" Dude">`, which will break...

Comment: @Fred, i posted almost the same answer. Is it not ok to post answer to this type of questions?

Comment: @manian- Your answer showed an example of how to properly (Almost) structure the markup, so it's not the same answer.  You're not getting upvoted / attention because your answer is 4 minutes later than this one.

Comment: @manian If you look at their original post (if you're able to) https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/44464794/1 to which I edited my comment about, you will see why I wrote that. (edit): being *"You missed the quotes around the value attribute."*. It's ok, but a better answer always helps.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - can everyone see revisions? Does it require a certain level of rep?

Comment: @cale_b TBH; I don't know (it's been too long, lol). I'll edit my comment to them. Edit: edited.

Answer (score 1):

```
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($rue); ?>" />
```

Don't forget quotes around the value.  Also be sure to use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape your arbitrary text data for use in HTML.  Otherwise, you risk creating invalid HTML.

Comment: This is the only correct answer.  You MUST use htmlspecialchars before presenting to a user, or the HTML can break!

Answer (score 0):

Please add double quotes for the value attributes of the field like below,

```
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $rue; ?>" >
```

Comment: This is incomplete.  You have the opportunity to *teach*, so be sure to teach the user about the importance of htmlspecialchars as well.

Comment: Yeah @cale_b, I got it thanks. I will consider your input in my future posts. Since Brad posted the correct answer, Is it ok if I edit my answer now?

Comment: Absolutely! Always feel free to edit your answer to make it clearer / higher quality!